# Looping checkedlistbox in TabPage

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, controls

while searching my solution 
found this article
 [Loop through controls in TabControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744429/loop-through-controls-in-tabcontrol)
it indeed helped me 
and I succeeded to create a loop through my needed TabPage
but it changes only the first checkedlistbox ( I know Why ! )
what I don't understand is how to change all the items I loop 
I know I need to use something like: 
`_C.items.add(value);`
this is the code:

```
foreach (TabPage TPage in ShiftsViewTab.TabPages)
            {
                if (TPage.Name.Equals("tabPage2"))
                {
                    var TabPageControlls = TPage.Controls;
                    foreach( Control _C in TabPageControlls)
                    if (_C is CheckedListBox)
                    {
                        checkedListBox1.Items.Clear();
                        foreach (string _Val in Settings.Default.ShiftList)
                        {
                            checkedListBox1.Items.Add(_Val);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

tried to use:

```
foreach (TabPage TPage in ShiftsViewTab.TabPages)
            {
                if (TPage.Name.Equals("tabPage2"))
                {
                    var TabPageControlls = TPage.Controls;
                    foreach(CheckedListBox _C in TabPageControlls)
                        _C.Items.Clear();
                        foreach (string _Val in Settings.Default.ShiftList)
                        {
                            _C.Items.Add(_Val);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```

but then encountered a problem with other controlls ...
Please advise
Thanks!!

Comment: I know it loops all the needed controlls ( checkedlistboxes ) with the upper code but changes 7 times the first checkedlistbox ( as hard coded )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this. The syntax is a little different; it uses a LINQ to make the code a bit shorter.

Basically, the first two lines of code check that "tabPage2" exists and just returns if it doesn't.

Then in the `foreach` block, the `OfType<>` method gets only controls of type `CheckedListBox`.

I also used `AddRange` so you could eliminate the inner-most `foreach` loop, but it requires an extra cast, which I can't test at the moment to be absolutely sure it works.

```
var tabPage2 = ShiftsViewTab.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>()
                            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "tabPage2");

if (tabPage2 == null)
    return;

foreach (var clb in tabPage2.Controls.OfType<CheckedListBox>())
{
    clb.Items.Clear();

    clb.Items.AddRange(Settings.Default.ShiftList.Cast<object>().ToArray());
}
```

Comment: from some reason I get an error on the `var tabPage2 = ShiftsViewTab.TabPages.Cast<TabPage>
                            .SingleOrDefault(x => x.Name == "tabPage2");` error on the `Cast<TabPage>`

Comment: it was already in the using statement, the error I get is: Error 1 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Can you change or explain how it should be ? ( Thanks!! )

Comment: the () .... got it ... Thanks !! although I figured it out my self ( in a different way) this one looks simpler ... THANKS !!!!

Answer (score 0):

Ok,
apparently didn't look deep enough...
found the answer here:
[Convert 'Control' to textbox and assign it a value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13362904/convert-control-to-textbox-and-assign-it-a-value)
this is the working code:

```
foreach (TabPage TPage in ShiftsViewTab.TabPages)
            {
                if (TPage.Name.Equals("tabPage2"))
                {
                    var TabPageControlls = TPage.Controls;
                    foreach( Control _C in TabPageControlls)
                    if (_C is CheckedListBox)
                    {
                        ((CheckedListBox)_C).Items.Clear();
                        foreach (string _Val in Settings.Default.ShiftList)
                        {
                            ((CheckedListBox)_C).Items.Add(_Val);
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
```